# Unable to connect to bioconductor website

Tags: r, bioconductor, internet-connection

I run RStudio (0.99.878) with R Version R-3.2.3 on Windows 7.

When I try to install packages from bioconductor with the following command I get an error message:

> source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
>      Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
>        cannot open the connection
>      In addition: Warning message:
>      In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
>        unable to connect to 'bioconductor.org' on port 80.

I thought it was a problem with the proxy settings/firewall, but exactly the same code works fine when run in R (It gave me a warning ('lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.3/library"' is not writable), but asked if I wanted to save it in another folder, then it worked).

I tried running RStudio as Administrator and I also unchecked the "Use Internet Explorer library/proxy for HTTP", as those steps were recommended elsewhere for this problem, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the local IT admin was just here and has changed the settings for RStudio (Right click on RStudio -> Properties -> ...), which did not help.
When trying whether the code would work I copied it from the bioconductor website and it worked: the difference is that it uses http**s** instead of http in my original code!

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when I download a file using

```
> source("http://www.statmethods.net/RiA/wmc.txt")
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: '安全频道支持出错'
```

Then I try

```
> options(download.file.method="libcurl", url.method="libcurl")
> source("http://www.statmethods.net/RiA/wmc.txt")
> wmc
```

It worked